# Dynamic Fields and BootstrapValidator

Tags: jquery, jqbootstrapvalidation

I'm workin' on my wedding-website. Since I have added a dynamic field to add more names the `jqBootstrapValidator` gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

I have tried everything but it does not work =(

Here's the Link to my page: [www.melanie-und-nino.ch](http://www.melanie-und-nino.ch)

Thank you!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/tapkfnej/

Comment: Got it: The newest jquery helped

Comment: Glad you got it fixed; hope the wedding goes well